# Query builder with max()

Tags: laravel-4

I am trying to rewrite this sql to laravel 4

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    SolutionFile
WHERE
    SolutionFile.group_id = $group_id and
    version = (
         SELECT
             max(s1.version)
         FROM
             SolutionFile s1
         WHERE
             s1.group_id = $group_id
    )
```

I wrote this request

```
SolutionFile::where('group_id', '=', $group_id)
    ->whereRaw('version = (select max(`version`) from files where group_id = ' . $group_id . ')')->get();
```

which works perfectly, but I want to rewrite it in "laravel way" without whereRaw.
I tried this request

```
SolutionFile::where('group_id', '=', $group_id)
    ->where(function($query) use($group_id) {
            return $query->where('version', '=', function() use($group_id) {
                return SolutionFile::where('group_id', '=', $group_id)->max('version');
            });
        });
```

but it returns an empty set.

Is there any way to rewrite it? Where did I make a mistake in last request?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found simple solution for this

```
SolutionFile::where('group_id', '=', $group_id)
                        ->where(function($query) use($group_id) {
                            return $query->where('version', '=', SolutionFile::where('group_id', '=', $group_id)->max('version'));
                        })->get()
```

There was no need to use `function()` as third param, only result from this function.